# Error running Jar file in Hadoop's MapReduce program

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, mapreduce

I'm trying to compile my code into a JAR file for use with Hadoop's MapReduce. My main class is VectorMaker.java and the director structure is as follows.

```
RandomForestVectors
 /bin
 /lib
   /hadoop-core-1.2.0.jar
   /mahout-core-0.7.jar
   /mahout-math-0.7.jar
   /opencsv-2.3.jar
 /VectorMaker.java
```

These are the commands I'm using to make my JAR file.

```
   javac -classpath "./lib/*" -d ./bin ./VectorMaker.java
   jar cf VectorMaker.jar -C "./bin/" . &
```

This is the command I used to try and run my JAR file as Hadoop MapReduce program.

```
hadoop jar VectorMaker.jar VectorMaker user/starmine/AlphaDefault/mahout/random_forest/prevectors  /user/starmine/AlphaDefault/mahout/random_forest/test1


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/mahout/math/VectorWritable
    at VectorMaker.main(VectorMaker.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I know I need to somehow make my JAR file contain all my dependencies but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all your dependencies in your classpath, including all the Mahout libraries. Alternatively you can specify the path through -classpath while compiling you program.

**javac -classpath -classpath $MAHOUT_HOME/lib/***

Comment: I'm sorry but did you mean **javac -classpath $MAHOUT_HOME/lib/**. Why wouldn't it work if I simply reference the jar files in my lib folder a.k.a **javac -classpath "./lib/*" -d ./bin ./VectorMaker.java**

Comment: It should work. I was just trying to make sure that you have added mahout jars as well.